# how to get the data of a json in php

Tags: php, json

I'm using web services in PHP but it returns a json that I can't access to an specific value like CodMateria.. Could you help me please??
I was trying to use:

```
$materia->GetResult->Materias->CodMateria;
```

The result that i can't access:

```
string(934) "{"GetResult":{"Materias":[{"CodMateria":"001","Materia":"Math","paralelo":"A"},
{"CodMateria":"002","Materia":"Math2","paralelo":"B"},
{"CodMateria":"003","Materia":"Math3","paralelo":"C"},
{"CodMateria":"004","Materia":"Math4","paralelo":"D"}]}}"
```

Comment: Just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the array out of JSON string

Comment: use json_decode and then use it like associative array

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to access a value..

Comment: There are more than one `CodMateria` inside `Materias`

Comment: @carla noriega use json_decode($materia, true);

Comment: This question can't be in `soap` tag.

Comment: An exhaustive answer to this question already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have mentioned, you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

$jsonData = '{"GetResult":{"Materias":[{"CodMateria":"001","Materia":"Math","paralelo":"A"},
{"CodMateria":"002","Materia":"Math2","paralelo":"B"},
{"CodMateria":"003","Materia":"Math3","paralelo":"C"},
{"CodMateria":"004","Materia":"Math4","paralelo":"D"}]}}';

$materia = json_decode($jsonData);

echo $materia->GetResult->Materias[0]->CodMateria;
```

Outputs:

```
001
```

Sample [Eval](https://eval.in/570452)

---

**Alternatively,**

You can use `json_decode($jsonData, true);` to convert yours into array. In that case you need to access like this:

```
<?php

$jsonData = '{"GetResult":{"Materias":[{"CodMateria":"001","Materia":"Math","paralelo":"A"},
{"CodMateria":"002","Materia":"Math2","paralelo":"B"},
{"CodMateria":"003","Materia":"Math3","paralelo":"C"},
{"CodMateria":"004","Materia":"Math4","paralelo":"D"}]}}';

$materia = json_decode($jsonData, true);

echo $materia["GetResult"]["Materias"][0]["CodMateria"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `json_decode()`. There are multiple `codeMateria` so in order to access first one use:

```
$materia->GetResult->Materias[0]->CodMateria
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, you need to specify if you want an associative array instead of an object from json_decode, this would be the code:

json_decode($jsondata, true);

http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

Try using [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
<?php
$strJson = '{"GetResult":{"Materias":[{"CodMateria":"001","Materia":"Math","paralelo":"A"},
{"CodMateria":"002","Materia":"Math2","paralelo":"B"},
{"CodMateria":"003","Materia":"Math3","paralelo":"C"},
{"CodMateria":"004","Materia":"Math4","paralelo":"D"}]}}';

$arrJson = json_decode($strJson);

foreach($arrJson->GetResult->Materias as $objResult)
{
    echo "<br>".$objResult->CodMateria;
}
?>
```

This will give output like below:

> 001
>
> 002
>
> 003
>
> 004

In similar way, you can access other values as well..!

e.g.

```
$objResult->Materia;
$objResult->paralelo;
```